# Subtract content of vector from scalar

Tags: c++, sse, avx

I try to optimize by code for different SIMD architectures. What is best way to calculate the following:

For SSE:

```
float  s = something  
__m128 v = calculation result  

s -= v[0] + v[1] + v[2] + v[3]
```

At the moment I calculate the horizontal sum by:

```
__m128 sum = _mm_hadd_ps( v, v )  
       sum = _mm_hadd_ps( sum, sum )  

s -= _mm_cvtss_f32( sum )
```

Is there some cool optimization possible ?

Comment: That's 3 instructions - it's hard to see how you'd beat it.

Comment: As Paul said, there is no room for optimization since you only have 4 instructions. Do you have that embedded in a loop, or is that a pattern of a code that you have to vectorize? If so, could you perhaps show the whole code?

Comment: Like @a3mlord said, if that's inside a loop, only do the horizontal op at the end of the loop.  Horizontal ops are significantly slower than in-lane ops.